# How to get the offsetLeft of an element dynamically?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a table and I want align an element outside the table to a column. I thought I could get the offsetLeft property to calculate this. But this didn´t work out for me.

```
ngOnInit(){
  ...
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.setOffset);
}
```

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.setOffset();
}
```

```
setOffset(){
  this.offsetLeft = document.getElementById("myId").offsetLeft;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Get position of HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576008/angular-2-get-position-of-html-element)

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576216/7124761

Comment: You should be able to align DOM elements vertically using just CSS. Can you explain why you can't do it with CSS?

Comment: Because it should align dynamically because column width is also choosen auto.